# Add script to Sparkview page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I have an application based on Sparkview. I need to feed the current url to some jquery, I could do with doing something along the lines of http://forums.asp.net/t/1550405.aspx

I tried to modify the application.spark and add

```
<script type="text/javascript">var baseUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>'</script>
```

Unfortunately I get an exception The name 'ResolveUrl' does not exist in the current context. I dont know much about sparkview, so if anyone could help it would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var baseUrl = window.location.pathname;</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

just as an FYI, Spark will resolve any `~/` paths it finds without an explicit call to ResolveUrl.  for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="~/Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <%= Url.Content("~") %>
```